# How do I root my Sonim XP8?

Tags: rooting, root-access, bootloader, bootloader-lock

I'm working on rooting a Sonim XP8. This is a pretty obscure device, so it isn't easy to root. A lot of the normal options (fastboot, rooting apps, etc.) don't work because it's a pretty locked-down phone.
I'm following [this great tutorial](https://xdaforums.com/t/sonim-xp8-root.3851187/post-80585313) on XDA Developers. It is pretty much the only tutorial for my specific phone on the internet. It is pretty complicated as it uses Qualcomm's QPST tools to change the emmc data of the phone to flash a custom ROM. 
My ultimate goal is to eventually get a Generic System Image of [e/OS](https://doc.e.foundation/support-topics/install-GSI) installed, but I am having trouble along the way. I'm stuck on step 1 part 3 of the Magisk rooting tutorial on the forum.

Here is my problem:
I am trying to run `fh_loader.exe  --convertprogram2read --port=\\.\COM<#> --sendxml=<xmlfile.xml> --lun=0  --memoryname=emmc --noprompt --reset` while my phone is in EDL mode to copy all the system files as a backup. I get an error message when I do so, which is below:

```
INFO: FH_LOADER WAS CALLED EXACTLY LIKE THIS
************************************************
fh_loader.exe --port=\\.\COM3 --convertprogram2read --sendxml=backup.xml --lun=0 --memoryname=emmc --noprompt --reset
************************************************

12:40:37: INFO: Current working dir (cwd): C:\Program Files (x86)\Qualcomm\QPST\bin\
12:40:37: INFO: Showing network mappings to allow debugging
12:40:37: INFO:



12:40:37: INFO: Trying to store 'backup.xml' in string table
12:40:37: INFO: Looking for file 'backup.xml'


         _____
        |  ___|
        | |__ _ __ _ __ ___  _ __
        |  __| '__| '__/ _ \| '__|
        | |__| |  | | | (_) | |
        \____/_|  |_|  \___/|_|


12:40:37: {ERROR: Could not access 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Qualcomm\QPST\bin\' with acess mode 'rb'}
```

So for some reason the `fh_loader` tool can't access the folder at which I'm trying to execute the command, even though I am running my command prompt in administrator mode and I am located in the same folder as the executable for that command.

Any advice or help would be appreciated.